# By Tomcat Localhost Access Log can we say " A Java Web Application is up and running "

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7

By Tomcat Localhost Access Log can we say  A Java Web Application is up and running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The access log records client activity and an application can be up and running even if nobody is connected.

Comment: But tomcat keeps on writing in localhost logs with the ip address of the host

Comment: If there are not GET or POST requests I doubt the log will contain much info

Comment: Actually the problem is that in the month of October the tomcat is writing the log after ever minute with the host ip address for say 10.236.546.01 . But in November it not showing any log from host ip address  and even the logs are getting delayed by a gap of 1 hour sometimes. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Is there any one who can help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a network monitor installed on the server which was creating the logs after every minute in tomcat localhost access log.